# Maximum current for a single-core cable?

Tags: power-supply, current, cables, amperage

I want to connect the cables of a LiPo 7.4 V 2200 mAh battery, to a breadboard. However, the only way to make this happens is to solder the ends of the battery cables with a single-core cable with solid conductor.

**Is this a safe option or there is the risk of damaging the single-core cable?** As far as I know, the current draw will be about 700 mA.

Comment: Please add information about wire gauge or core diameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically - for 700mA you should use AWG 23 wire. You can use [this table](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm) for choosing wires.

AWG 23 is 0.57404mm core diameter (or 0.0226 inch core diameter).

Practically - if wire is short (few cm/inches) - you can use AWG24 or AWG25 wire and there will be no damage at all. Even thinner wire probably could survive 700mA without damage.

Note, that wire current ratings are usually determined by voltage drop/resistance. This is not maximum current without damage.

**You should worry more about wire<->breadboard connection resistance.**

Many breadboards on the market are poor quality and 700mA current may cause some voltage drop on connection between wire and breadboard conductive part. For relatively high currents (>500mA) I'm using double wires sometimes - to make sure that connection is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The optimum size for solid-core wire to fit snugly into a solderless breadboard is [AWG 22](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) (0.64mm diameter), and that will be fine. 12" of AWG 22 wire (two 6" leads) will drop only about 11mV at 700mA, which is pretty much negligible.

700mA is towards the upper end for a breadboard, and you may see some significant voltage drop and heating if the contact turns out to be flaky.

Do not use the plug wire style unless you verify the wire size is substantial- I've measured them at about AWG 28 (0.3mm), which is a little light. The actual current rating of wire will depend on the insulation used and the environment (other wires and temperature) but ignoring voltage drop, a couple hundred mA would be a reasonable limit for cheap PVC wire in a lab environment.

[image]

Comment: I always thought the cross-sectional area of copper determined current handling.  The insulation used defines the voltage handling of the wire.

Comment: The cross sectional area of copper (assuming it's round) determines the heat load and thus the temperature rise. The wire current capability (for insulated wire) depends on how hot you're willing to allow the insulation to get. If the insulation is rated for 90°C and the temperature in the box could get to 89.9°C, then you can't put barely any current through the wire. If the insulation is rated for 200°C (aerospace PTFE insulation), it's in open air,and you're willing to allow it to get that hot (and drop that much voltage, which is a separate question), an AWG20 wire can handle close to 20A!

Comment: Yes, but how little voltage would you get out of the end of it after all that heat loss?  Current handling is about more than just heat - it's about voltage drop.

Comment: @Majenko There are **dual** constraints and **both** must be met. I therefore addressed both in my answer above.

Comment: I could encase a wire in ceramic insulation. But what what use would that be if the copper inside turned to liquid from its own self generated heat? Insulation temperature rating is for environmental temperature, not wire temperature. Only an insane person would take the temperature of a conductor over the voltage drop from the conductor itself as the lower limit. If a wire gets hot enough to even soften the weakest of insulation then you are doing something drastically wrong.

Comment: @Majenko Not true. Insulation temperature rating must take **both** environmental temperature and self-heating (individual and from adjacent wires) fully into account. To do otherwise would be negligent, and, IMO, legally actionable if licensed engineer did so and it caused harm.

Comment: But causing the wire to self-heat so much is not something that any sane engineer would do.  The cross-sectional area rating (AWG - look it up!) takes into account a specific maximum self heating amount (10°C IIRC above ambient).  Getting a cable to self heat to 85°C would therefore mean it was in a 75°C environment - so would you really be using just an 85°C cable in that environment?  If you follow the AWG rules you cannot possibly come close (unless you're being stupid) to insulation melting temperatures.

Comment: What do you think "AWG rules" are? Who do you think writes them? AWG stands for American Wire Gauge. Gauge refers to the dimensional size. It's just the diameter of the wire, nothing else.

Comment: Yes, and the dimensional size defines the current carrying capacity through a mathematical formula.  For power transmission, 700 circular mils per amp, and for chassis wiring 200 circular mils per amp.

Comment: Show me that "mathematical formula" in UL CSA or FAA documents and I'll concede the point.

Comment: No, I won't.  The point is that you flatly state "The actual current rating of wire will depend on the insulation used and the environment" which, as you have already said in your previous comments, is a falsehood. You claim "There are dual constraints and both must be met. I therefore addressed both in my answer above", and yet you don't - you only address the insulation temperature and specifically "ignore voltage drop" (your words, not mine). As the answer stands it implies that the ONLY thing to worry about is the temperature of the insulation, which is complete bullshit to be blunt.

Comment: ?? I address the voltage drop as 16mV, which is negligible on a 7V battery, that should be obvious.

Comment: You mention that in passing then brush it aside. Your further answer then leads me to believe I could safely use 40AWG wire (fuses at 1.77A) if the insulation were good enough, but you wouldn't as the voltage drop would be extortionate (65× the resistance of 22AWG). You just say to ignore that though as if it has no bearing on anything. You HAVE to take into account the resistance - not just for safety but for working within acceptable losses. Those losses can have huge effect even before the wire gets remotely warm. Following those well established rules of thumb you'll never get even ...

Comment: ... slightly close to insulation melting points. But, drape your wires across a heater and it'll melt, short circuit, and blow up.

Answer (score 0):

Solid core cables lack the flexibility and mechanical robustness that stranded cable gives you.  A solid core is more likely to fatigue over time at stress points like where it enters a solder joint.  That is why in general flying leads (like power cables, network cables, etc) are stranded cable.  Conversely, solid core cable performs better when being used with things like screw connectors, or with individual-wire IDC connectors (such as RJ-45 "punch down" wall sockets), where the cable is fixed in place and doesn't move.

The current carrying capacity of stranded vs solid core is (virtually) the same for the same cross-sectional area of copper.